# Can the negation of an unprovable true statement be added as an axiom?

Tags: logic, provability

Let $S$ be some statement which is unprovable but true in an axiomatic system $T$. If $T$ is consistent, then adding $S$ as an axiom of $T$ keeps the system consistent. But what about adding $\neg S$ as an axiom?

For example, the continuum hypothesis is unprovable in ZFC, and we can add it or its negation as an axiom with no problem.

However, if the Goldbach conjecture is unprovable, it must be true, since if it were false we'd be able to find a counter-example, and check that it is a counter-example. Hence we wouldn't be able to add the negation of the Goldbach conjecture as an axiom if it is unprovable. Does this imply it is provable? Or is this okay?

Comment: Why does the Goldbach conjecture have to be true? How do you know there isn't a counter-example that is too big to write down?

Comment: Yes, we can add the negation of Goldbach conjecture. "True" applies not to the formal system itself (in this case arithmetic), but to its "intended" model. If the Goldbach conjecture is unprovable it means that it has a counterexample in a non-standard model of arithmetic (by [Gödel's completeness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem)). If we add the negation our theory will no longer describe "intuitive" integers (assuming there is such a thing) but it will still be a fine theory without contradictions.

Comment: @JohnDouma: If the Goldbach conjecture is _false_, then it is disprovable in PA -- so, contrapositively, if the Goldbach conjecture is _undecidable_ in PA (not merely unprovable as the OP says), then it is _true in $\mathbb N$_.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Then why is it called a conjecture? If you can reason that it must be true, isn't that a proof?

Comment: @JohnDouma: Why do you think I can reason it must be true? I'm reasoning that **if** it is undecidable in PA, **then** it is true. But I have no idea _whether_ it is undecidable in PA.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Then how do we know it is true? I apologize if I am being thick but I thought you were saying it must be true as a response to my question of how we know it is true.

Comment: @JohnDouma: Why do you think I claim it must be true? I'm claiming no such thing. I'm giving a _sufficient_ condition for it to be true, but I'm not claiming that condition holds.

Comment: @HenningMakholm That's why I was confused. I simply asked how we know there isn't a counter-example. I wasn't expecting someone to explain what I'd need to show if there wasn't.

Comment: @JohnDouma: I'm confused why you're asking that, since nobody has claimed that we know there isn't a counterexample.

Comment: @HenningMakholm "since if it were false we'd be able to find a counter-example" confused me.

Comment: You’ve probably heard at some point that soundness (with respect to $\mathbb N$) is a much more stringent requirement than consistency. There are lots of examples of that. Assuming PA is consistent, PA + not Con(PA) is consistent. It is also unsound. Similarly if the Goldbach conjecture is undecidable in PA, PA+ not GC is both consistent and wrong (about $\mathbb N$.)

Comment: @JohnDouma: Ah, I see. That was under the assumption "if the Goldbach conjecture is unprovable" (by which the OP meant undecidable).

Comment: @PatrickStevens Thank you to you and Henning for the clarifications. I understand the statement that confused me now.

Comment: Hang on, @HenningMakholm, is there a difference between "unprovable" and "undecidable"?

Comment: @Sambo: Yes: $\varphi$ is "unprovable" if $\varphi$ cannot be proved, and is "undecidable" if neither $\varphi$ nor $\neg\varphi$ can be proved.

Comment: Oh, I see. The distinction is that an unprovable $\varphi$ could simply be false, correct?

Comment: @Sambo: An undecidable sentence might also "simply be false" in a particular model. An unprovable sentence is either _undecidable_ or _disprovable_.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Right, of course. I need to work on my terminology!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can add the negation of any unprovable statement as a new axiom to the theory and still get a consistent theory out of it.

(If the extended theory proved a contradiction, this would directly be a proof of the original "unprovable" statement, which therefore wouldn't be unprovable after all).

If the new axiom happens to be *false* in the interpretation of the theory you had in mind (such as the actual $\mathbb N$), this interpretation will not be a model any more, of course. The extended theory will have other models that are *non-standard* models of your original theory.

Comment: So in the case of the Goldbach conjecture, if the statement is true but undecidable, adding its negation asserts the existence of an even number which is not the sum of two primes. This number would therefore have to be something which isn't part of what we usually think of as $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: @Sambo Correct.

Comment: So that means that if the Goldbach conjecture is undecidable, then it must be true in "the actual $\mathbb{N}$", even though we could add its negation as an axiom and end up with a consistent theory.

Comment: @Sambo Again correct. (Note that there still seems to be much more hope of proving Goldbach fair and square than of figuring out a way to prove it independent of say PA)

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications!